# Consecutive "X"s drawLine() Java

Tags: java, for-loop, graphics, draw

So I am currently trying to figure out how to make a program that draws 5 consecutive "X"s using a for-loop. I'm trying to make the lines spaced apart by 30 px like so \ ...\ ...\ ...\ ...\
This is what I have so far:

```
int y = 50;
int x = 70;

for (int z = 0; z <= 150; z += 30){
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.drawLine(x+z*2, y+30, x+z, y);
}
```

This code only draws only draws one line of the X, but I need to figure out how to draw one line before I can draw the second one. 
Currently it's printing the lines evenly spaced 30 pixels apart, but through every loop the angle of the line is getting larger and larger, when it should be 45.
Btw I am aware there are plenty of other ways for me to do this, but I am required to only use for-loops.

Comment: Remember, `drawLine` works by drawing a line from point A (x/y) TO point B (x/y), not width/height like many of the other graphics methods ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're multiplying `z` by 2 for one x-point, but not the other. You probably want to add a constant value, instead of multiplying. Right now, the offset of each step will be the value of `z`, eg increasing by 30 each time.

I would change your `drawLine` call to `g.drawLine(x + z + 30, y + 30, x + z, y);`.

Comment: That worked perfectly! I knew I needed a constant in their, but I didn't quite know how to implement it. I had been playing around with the numbers and equations for a couple of hours and it was that easy. Thank you.